# How to cast column data type in hibernate criteria?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, orm, hibernate-criteria

I have a query like below.It is working fine ,But I want to write same query by using hibernate Criteria any one help me.

**SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
ORDER BY
        CAST (mycol AS DECIMAL)**

Comment: you can go for HQL itself for those kind of requirements

Answer (score 1):

Try with this query:

```
List orders = session.createCriteria(Order.class)
    .addOrder(new org.hibernate.criterion.Order("mycol", true) {
        @Override
        public String toSqlString(Criteria criteria, CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery) throws HibernateException {
            return "cast(mycol as DECIMAL)";
        }
    })
    .list();
```